# Fragmenting Backbone collection view based on some criteria

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

I'm a bit new to [BackboneJS](http://backbonejs.org) and [Marionette](https://github.com/derickbailey/backbone.marionette), and I'm a bit stuck on how to implement some tricky behaviour with a [CollectionView](https://github.com/derickbailey/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.collectionview.md). Suppose I have a list of appointments, each with an appointment date/time (stored as a unix timestamp, but that's not important).

When I display these, I'd like to display them as follows:

#### Today

- Meeting A (10:00 AM)
- Meeting B (11:00 AM)
- Meeting C (1:00 PM)
- ... and 4 more

#### Next 7 days

- Meeting D (Monday at 3 PM)
- Meeting E (Tuesday at 2 PM)
- ... and 7 more

The approach I'm considering is to pull one collection from the server for the next 7 days (including today) and then do 2 views over the collection (one for today, and one for the week). Here's what I'm struggling with:

- AFAIK, the Marionette.CollectionView renders *all* the elements in a collection. Is there an easy way to override this behaviour to only render, say, 3 or 4 items?
- How do I deal with the *... and n more* line? It's not really a model, but its data is computed from the underlying collection.

If it makes a difference, I'm using @SlexAxton's [requirejs-handlebars](https://github.com/SlexAxton/require-handlebars-plugin) project for templating.

Comment: Maybe this will perfectly fit for logic inside templates :) you got to do certain things even though it is nor right. I constructed a **treeview** using **treenode** as `model` and `single template` that contained logic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might use a `CompositeView` instead of a `CollectionView`. So you define yourself the `collection` attribute to use a subset you want, and then you can display the "X more…" link.

It could be something like:

```
EventView = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend
  template: 'event'


EventsView = Backbone.Marionette.CompositeView.extend
  itemView: EventView
  template: 'events'

  initialize: (attributes)->
    @extractSubset(attributes.collection)

  extractSubset: (collection)->
    @collection  = new EventsCollection(collection.filterByWhatYouWant())
    @othersCount = collection.length - @collection.length

  appendHtml: (collectionView, itemView)->
    collectionView.$('.events').append(itemView.el)

  serializeData: ->
    othersCount:      @othersCount
    andAnyOtherThing: 'you need in the template'
```

Comment: Oh, awesome. I'll give that a shot and let you know. Thanks!